# React component table is being rendered multiple times or duplicated after updating state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm updating state with changes in props by replacing the old state. In render, the data is either being duplicated or rendering multiple times from the state after it is reset with new props. It is happening from after the first render.

This is the work flow of the app- a fetch occurs first when user searches for a location. It gets "recommended places" around the users location. It puts the data into redux store as "recommended places". The components in question renders the data from the store [first pic], which happens nicely. When filter buttons are clicked, this time it fetches with user location and the filter, and puts the data in redux store, e.g, restaurants=[], bars=[] etc.. The components should get the new data from the store and re-render. That's where my problem is. When re-rendering it seems to duplicate the data [second pic].

This is the component in question-

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default class Results extends Component {
  state = {
    places: []
  };

getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(prevProps) {

  const {places, restaurant, bar, coffee, bank, park} = 
  this.props.results;

  if (prevProps.results.places !== places) {
      this.setState({ places });
  }
  if (prevProps.results.restaurant !== restaurant) {
      this.setState({ places: restaurant });
  }
  if (prevProps.results.bar !== bar) {
      this.setState({ places: bar });
  }
  if (prevProps.results.coffee !== coffee) {
      this.setState({ places: coffee });
  }
  if (prevProps.results.bank !== bank) {
      this.setState({ places: bank });
  }
  if (prevProps.results.park !== park) {
      this.setState({ places: park });
  }
}

renderPlaces = () => this.state.places.map((place, i) => {
  if (place.type || place.type === "Recommended Places") {
      return place.items.map((item, i) => (
          <tbody key={item.venue.id}>
              <tr className="table-secondary">
                  <th scope="row">{item.venue.name}</th>
                  <td>
                      <h6>
                          {`${(item.venue.location.distance / 
                           1609.344).toFixed(2)}`}{" "}
                          <cite>miles</cite>
                      </h6>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      ));
  }
  return this.state.places.map((place, i) => (
      <tbody key={place.id}>
          <tr className="table-secondary">
              <th scope="row">{place.name}</th>
              <td>
                  <h6>
                      {`${(place.location.distance / 
                      1609.344).toFixed(2)}`}{" "}
                      <cite>miles</cite>
                  </h6>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
   ));
})

render() {
  return (
      <React.Fragment>
          {this.renderPlaces()}
      </React.Fragment>
  );
 }
}

Results.propTypes = {
  places: PropTypes.array,
  restaurant: PropTypes.array,
  coffee: PropTypes.array,
  bar: PropTypes.array,
  banks: PropTypes.array,
  parks: PropTypes.array
};
```

**Below is the Parent Component-**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Results from "./Results";

class ResultList extends Component {
  state = {
    places: [],
    restaurant: [],
    bar: [],
    coffee: [],
    bank: [],
    park: []
  };

  getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(prevProps) {
    const {
      recommendedPlaces,
      restaurants,
      coffee,
      bars,
      banks,
      parks
    } = this.props;

    if (prevProps.recommendedPlaces !== recommendedPlaces) {
      this.setState({ places: recommendedPlaces });
      // returning a snapshot just in case I want to use..⬇
      // componentDidUpdate in the future
      return recommendedPlaces;
    }
    if (prevProps.restaurants !== restaurants) {
      this.setState({ restaurant: restaurants });
      // returning a snapshot just in case I want to use..⬇
      // componentDidUpdate in the future
      return restaurants;
    }
    if (prevProps.bars !== bars) {
      this.setState({ bar: bars });
      // returning a snapshot just in case I want to use..⬇
      // componentDidUpdate in the future
      return bars;
    }
    if (prevProps.coffee !== coffee) {
      this.setState({ coffee });
      // returning a snapshot just in case I want to use..⬇
      // componentDidUpdate in the future
      return coffee;
    }
    if (prevProps.banks !== banks) {
      this.setState({ bank: banks });
      // returning a snapshot just in case I want to use..⬇
      // componentDidUpdate in the future
      return banks;
    }
    if (prevProps.parks !== parks) {
      this.setState({ park: parks });
      // returning a snapshot just in case I want to use..⬇
      // componentDidUpdate in the future
      return parks;
    }

    return null;
  }

  render() {
    const { address, filterBy } = this.props;
    return (
      <table className="primary table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">
              {filterBy === null ? "Places" : filterBy.toUpperCase()}
              {
                // eslint-disable-next-line
              }{" "}
              near
              {
                // eslint-disable-next-line
              }{" "}
              {address.toUpperCase()}
            </th>
            {/* this.showPlaces(recommendedPlaces, restaurants, bars, parks) */}
            <th scope="col">Distance</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <Results results={this.state} />
      </table>
    );
  }
}

ResultList.propTypes = {
  address: PropTypes.string,
  filterBy: PropTypes.string,
  recommendedPlaces: PropTypes.array,
  restaurants: PropTypes.array,
  coffee: PropTypes.array,
  bars: PropTypes.array,
  banks: PropTypes.array,
  parks: PropTypes.array
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  recommendedPlaces: state.places.recommendedPlaces,
  restaurants: state.places.restaurants,
  coffee: state.places.coffee,
  bars: state.places.bars,
  banks: state.places.banks,
  parks: state.places.parks
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ResultList);
```

**Next two pictures are the rendered page.**

***First one is the first render when I search for a place. Rendering perfectly. It fetches and renders "recommended places" only.***

[image]

***Second is the render that happens after resetting the state when new props come in when clicked on the filter button to the left. It doesn't filter the places data. Instead it fetches and renders new data with the location and filter.***

[image]

Any help is much appreciated!

**https://codesandbox.io/s/zw33318484
Search for an address in the Autocomple search field. It should render middle of the page(ResultList.js and Result.js) with "recommended places". Then choose "restaurant" filter. Now it should re-render the restaurants that are in the store. Instead it just keeps adding on the restaurant on render. I think it is re-rendering and keeps concatenating the restaurant array in the props. It does so as many time that it re-renders.**

Comment: Please don't use pictures of code in your question. Include the actual code instead.

Comment: Please paste and edit your code instead of sending pictures of it. A working snippet of your problem would be even better

Comment: Why are you putting the props into state? If you are receiving what you need in props, just render from the props.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I put props into state so my render function isn't too long. I tried rendering with props. I tried checking for props length and rendering when full  but that way I have to check for every single props and didn't know how to render only the newest props.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I will delete the pictures of the code. Thanks

Comment: @Dean Rendering from props shouldn't look any different than rendering from state. Just replace `this.state` with `this.props` and get rid of the state. You don't need to look for what is "new".

Comment: @Treycos will delete the pic and post code. Thanks

Comment: @RyanCogswell If you look at the parent component, props are passed down as a whole state which has many different arrays. I'm trying to consolidate whatever props that gets passed down to one single point of data. I tried what you said before tho. It didn't work. Maybe I did it wrong

Comment: @RyanCogswell I think that you think places is the array that has everything. And filter button just filters the data in render?

Comment: @RyanCogswell But that's not what's happening. Places gets populated with recommended places only. Filter buttons fetches with the location and the filter. so everytime filter is updated it's completely new data.

Comment: Sorry, didn’t look closely enough. This still seems like a strange way to manage this information. It is difficult to help without seeing more of how the data gets managed outside of these two components.

Comment: @RyanCogswell So a fetch occurs first when user searches for a location. It gets "recommended places" around the users location. It puts the data into redux store as "recommended places". The components above renders the data from the store [first pic], which happens nicely. When filter buttons are clicked, this time it fetches with user location and the filter, and puts the data in redux store, e.g, restaurants=[], bars=[] etc.. The components above should get the new data from the store and re-render. That's where my problem is. When re-rendering it duplicates the data [second pic].

Comment: Is the redux data correct in the second case? It sounds like you’re describing issues that are outside of the code in these two components.

Comment: @RyanCogswell yup. redux data is correct. Would it help if I added the github link?

Comment: @Dean What would help the most is a working example (e.g. CodeSandbox) showing the behavior. Simplify as much as possible (should only need two of the filters, hard code the redux initial state and what data gets put in there after selecting a filter so that no fetching is involved) while still reproducing the problem.

Comment: @RyanCogswell https://codesandbox.io/s/zw33318484

Comment: @Dean Great. What are the exact steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @RyanCogswell search for a place from the autocomplete search to the upper left. Then add a filter.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thank you Ryan for being so patient!

Comment: @Dean Please give one specific example of what exact steps reproduce it (what to search for, what filter to select, and explain what you see and what you should see instead. Put all of this and the sandbox link into your question text so people don’t have to wade through the comments for it. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanCogswell sure. Search for "386 2nd Avenue, New York, NY, USA" in Autocomple search". Then choose "restaurant" filter.

Comment: @RyanCogswell After searching it should render Middle of the page(ResultList.js and Result.js) with "recommended places". Then choose "restaurant" filter. Now it should re-render the restaurants that are in the store. Instead it just keeps adding on the restaurant on render. I think it is re-rendering and keeps concatenating the restaurant array in the props. It does so as many time that it re-renders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in your `renderPlaces` function. Below is a simplified version to make it easier to see the structure.

```
renderPlaces = () => {
    this.state.places.map((place, i) => {
      if (place.type || place.type === "Recommended Places") {
          // When first selecting a location from the autocomplete search,
          // you execute this code
          return place.items.map((item, i) => (
              <tbody key={item.venue.id}>
                  {/* stuff to render a place */}
              </tbody>
          ));
      }
      // When you select a filter, you hit this condition instead.
      return this.state.places.map((place, i) => (
          <tbody key={place.id}>
              {/* stuff to render a place */}
          </tbody>
       ));
    })
};
```

When you first select a location, there is a single entry in `this.state.places` with `place.type` of "Recommended Places". That `place` has an array of `items` which drives the rendering. When you select a filter (e.g. "Restaurants"), `places` has multiple entries (10 in the case I saw) and none of them have a `type` so it hits the second condition. The second return does a `this.state.places.map` call, but you are still within the outer `this.state.places.map` call so you iterate through all the places once for each place. So the extra copies are not related to the number of re-renders, but just to the number of places. If you remove the second `this.state.places.map` as shown below it works fine (at least this aspect).

```
renderPlaces = () => {
    this.state.places.map((place, i) => {
      if (place.type || place.type === "Recommended Places") {
          return place.items.map((item, i) => (
              <tbody key={item.venue.id}>
                  {/* stuff to render a place */}
              </tbody>
          ));
      }
      return (
          <tbody key={place.id}>
              {/* stuff to render a place */}
          </tbody>
      );
    })
};
```

[image: Edit nearby]

Comment: Oh my God! That was just so stupid of me. I wasted half a day with tearing my hair out. Thank you so much Ryan! You are the man!